# looking for clarification about the pickle module

Tags: python-2.x

So I was wondering if someone could answer me a couple of questions regarding the pickle module:

1. Is there any threading involved when it loads/dumps?
2. does it return after it is completely done in pickle.dump()?
3. I have some code that is like this:

```
f=open(filename, 'wb')

pickle.dump)((my_dict, f, 2)

f.close()
```

But when I open the file it is human readable. According to the docs, protocol 2 is bytes, does that not mean it should not be human-readable?

These are probably really newbie questions but I appreciate your answers in this matter.